# Passing Credentials to Sql Report Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am pretty new in C# and my English is not so good - sorry in advance if I miss a point.

I tried to build an ASP.NET web site with a `ReportService` control. As you might already know, SSRS 2008 does not allow anonymous login. So, I tried to pass Credentials to SSRS which will be stored inside my web page so that users will be able to see the report without logging in.

I found the code below and put it on my `WebForm`, but I'm having a problem with the report parameters.

- If there are default values for the report parameters, the below code
  works okay.
- But, if I try to change the value of a parameter, the whole page is
  refreshed and before I  click the "View Report" button, all
  parameters are reset to default or null values.

Any suggestion on how to avoid refreshing the whole page, or another way to pass the login info to SSRS? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportViewer1.Width = 800;
        ReportViewer1.Height = 600;
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        IReportServerCredentials irsc =new CustomReportCredentials("administrator", "MYpassworw", "domena");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://192.168.0.1/ReportServer/");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/autonarudzba/listanarudzbi";
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }
}

public class CustomReportCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
{
     private string _UserName;
     private string _PassWord;
     private string _DomainName;

     public CustomReportCredentials(string UserName, string PassWord, string DomainName)
     {
        _UserName = UserName;
        _PassWord = PassWord;
        _DomainName = DomainName;
     }

     public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
     { 
        get { return null; } 
     } 

     public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
     {
        get { return new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _PassWord, _DomainName); }
     }

     public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user,
      out string password, out string authority)
     {
        authCookie = null;
        user = password = authority = null;
        return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure they dropped Anonymous auth from SSRS 2008?  You might just need to configure it in IIS?

Comment: From: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/jameswu/archive/2008/07/15/anonymous-access-in-sql-rs-2008.aspx

So what happened to the good old anonymous authentication is RS 2005? The short answer is that it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I really haven't messed with SSRS - but my ASP.NET hat tells me you may want to wrap that stuff in an `if (!IsPostBack)` block to keep it from running on the page refresh. My guess is that `ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh()` pulls the default values again.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack) 
    {
        ReportViewer1.Width = 800;
        ReportViewer1.Height = 600;
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        IReportServerCredentials irsc =new CustomReportCredentials("administrator", "MYpassworw", "domena");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://192.168.0.1/ReportServer/");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/autonarudzba/listanarudzbi";
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to cut out line ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh() but unfortunately same thing happened again.

Comment: Did you wrap it in a IsPostBack check?

Comment: ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials has no setter

Comment: Thanks for this tidbit.  I've been puzzled for several hours as to why the report would not render when I passed in credentials.  This is genius!

Answer (score 0):

I made new function and picked it up in the design view on properties, events, reportViewer. (In selection INIT i)

After that, the page works normally and I can change values for parameters.

Default.aspx  now looks like:

```
    </head>
      <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" onload="Admir">
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
         </div>
       </form>
    </body>
```

And Default.aspx.cs looks like this

```
 public void Admir(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportViewer1.Width = 800;
        ReportViewer1.Height = 600;
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials("administrator", "mypass", "domena");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://192.168.0.1/ReportServer/");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/autonarudzba/listanarudzbi";
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code in page load event to give parameters

```
ReportParameter[] reportParameterCollection = new ReportParameter[1]; //Array size describes the number of paramaters.
reportParameterCollection[0] = new ReportParameter();
reportParameterCollection[0].Name = "ACCMGR";   //Give Your Parameter Name
reportParameterCollection[0].Values.Add("12"); //Pass Parametrs's value here.
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameterCollection);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

I hope the this works for you

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution for this.
you have to set credentials first then you have to set parameter for reportviewer.

```
 rvCommon.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        rvCommon.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri("SSRSReportServerURL");
        rvCommon.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report Parts/CustomerMainReport2" ;

        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] RptParameters = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[1];
         rvCommon.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportCredentials("username", "password", "");

        RptParameters[0] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("CustomerId", "1");
        rvCommon.ServerReport.SetParameters(RptParameters);
        rvCommon.ServerReport.Refresh();
```