# How to use or get working: Reporting services report viewer component in VS.NET

Tags: c#, reporting, service, reportviewer

I am trying to write a simple web app (C# or VB.NET) to display a set of reports/subreports, but I can't seem to get access to the ReportViewer control.
I am using VS.NET express (2005 and 2010) and I know I need the reportviewer pluglin. but I have installed it but I can't seem to get it to appear in the toolbox.
I have tried to add a reference but VS does not like the DLL :P

Please guide me through a walk through!

Thanks.
M

Answer (score 0):

have you check this link?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ReportViewer.aspx

To create a Web page that contains the ReportViewer server control

1.Open and build ReportViewer.sln in Visual Studio .NET.

2.Create a new ASP.NET Web application in Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 200X.

3.Add a reference to ReportViewer.dll from the ReportViewer solution \bin folder. To do this, click Add/Remove Toolbox Items on the Tools menu. 
The Customize Toolbar dialog box opens.

4.In the Customize Toolbar dialog box, click the .NET Framework Components tab, and then click Browse.

5.Locate ReportViewer.dll in the bin directory of the ReportViewer project folder. Select ReportViewer.dll and click Open. 
The ReportViewer server control is now added to your Toolbox.

6.From the Toolbox, drag the ReportViewer server control onto the Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003 WebForm design surface. This creates a new ReportViewer object on your ASP.NET Web Forms page.

7.Set the ReportPath property of the control in the property window. For example, you can set the property to "/SampleReports/Company Sales".

8.Set the ServerUrl property in the property window. For example, you can set the property to http://localhost/reportserver.

9.In addition you can set the Parameters, Toolbar, and Zoom properties of the ReportViewer control. These correspond to the HTML Viewer commands of Reporting Services URL Access. For more information about these commands, see Using URL Access Parameters.

10.Size the control to render an appropriate report size.

11.If you set the Toolbar property of the control to false, the report is rendered on the WebForm design surface; otherwise start the ASP.NET Web application to render the report in your Web browser. Click Start on the Debug menu.

Answer (score 0):

[Take look my SO about Report Viewer, This considering that You use SQL Report server as online source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671694/passing-credentials-to-sql-report-server-2008)