# How to pass server/domain credentials when accessing SSRS report through SSRS Web service programmatically?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, credentials, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to render SSRS Report located on my remote report server in my ASP.NET MVC 4 app through reporting services web service programmatically.

how can i send the server (windows/domain credentials) at runtime?

tried below but no success.

```
ReportingService2010 service = new ReportingService();
service.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
service.Url = "http://MyReportServer/ReportServer/";
```

Comment: I think you need to pass the domain as a third parameter.

Comment: Yes you also  need to pass `domain` as third parameter. Take a look at here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @CoderofCode: can you please give an example?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671694/passing-credentials-to-sql-report-server-2008) and see the code from the question it is the good way to do it.If you want I Can post the code here from there but thats just copy paste job

Comment: service.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

Comment: what if you dont know the domain?

Comment: @CoderofCode: i am not using `ReportViewer` control.

Comment: my report server is located on cloud.

Comment: If the server isn't joined to a domain, try the machine name. And it doesn't matter where the server is located. Same for cloud and on-prem deployments.